# how to open a webpage using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How to resolve the below error in jmeter
1.) Request to open Google.com

[image]

2.) [image]

P.S: I have just started learning jmeter.
Which is the best way to learn it, please advice.

Comment: The text in the screenshots are not readable. Please update the images, or include the necessary text in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of creating a JMeter test is just recording it. JMeter comes with [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) which can be used for building a test plan skeleton via capturing browser requests, check out [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) for more information.

I would recommend attending [JMeter Academy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blazemeter-news/blazemeter-launches-jmeter-academy), this way you will be able to quickly ramp-up in JMeter in particular and performance testing in general. [Performance Testing Guidance for Web Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb924375.aspx) book is also very useful 
 for performance testing greenhorns.

---

In regards to the possible error, I cannot see the details, just a blind shot: are you behind a corporate proxy/firewall? If yes, you will need to "tell" JMeter the details of this proxy so it could access the Internet (same applies to "recording" approach of tests creation), see [Using JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) chapter for the relevant JMeter configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> JMeter is not a browser

See first page of [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

> JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does
>   it render the HTML pages as a browser does